# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "ISvgImage" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native

> Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: “ISvgImage” was not found
>   in the UIManager

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you linked admob using react-native link react-native-admob?

Comment: Yes, I have linked admob.

Comment: Post versions of react-native and admob version

Comment: "react-native-admob": "^2.0.0-beta.5",

Comment: react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.61.2

Comment: Can you try with 2.0.0-beta.6 and link it ahain

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similiar issue related to RNCViewPager(RNCViewPager was not found in the UIManager) in the following way:

I added the following to my `settings.gradle`

```
include ':@react-native-community_viewpager'
project(':@react-native-community_viewpager').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-community/viewpager/android')
```

Then I added the following to `app/build.gradle`

`implementation project(':@react-native-community_viewpager')`

I then updated my `Android Application class` with an import

`import com.reactnativecommunity.viewpager.RNCViewPagerPackage;`

and then added it to the list of RN Packages:

```
    private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
            return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
            return Arrays.asList(
                    new MainReactPackage(),
                    new MapsPackage(),
                    new Interactable(),
                    new LocationServicesPackage(),
                    new AnalyticsPackage(),
                    new ConfigPackage(),
                    new BlurViewPackage(),
                    new RNI18nPackage(),
                    new NavigationPackage(),
                    new RemoteConfigPackage(),
                    new LottiePackage(),
                    new ReanimatedPackage(),
                    new GeolocationPackage(),
                    new NetInfoPackage(),
                    new RNCViewPagerPackage()
            );
        }
    };
```

Full stacktrace and details are here:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27557